# Spring Reactive WebClient is not calling another service

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, spring-webflux

I have 2 Spring Boot microservices. Microservice (B) calls a reactive api exposed by Microservice (A).

Microservice (A) RestController code :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/documents")
public class ElasticDocumentController {

  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ElasticDocumentController.class);

  private final ElasticQueryService elasticQueryService;

  public ElasticDocumentController(ElasticQueryService queryService) {
    this.elasticQueryService = queryService;
  }

  @GetMapping(value = "/", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
  public Flux<ElasticQueryServiceResponseModel> getAllDocuments() {
    Flux<ElasticQueryServiceResponseModel> response = elasticQueryService.getAllDocuments();
    response = response.log();
    LOG.info("Returning from query reactive service for all documents");
    return response;
  }

}
```

When I call the getAllDocuments() api from Postman, I can see the documents scrolling in the output cosole. So Microservice (A) is correct.

But when I call the api from Microservice (B), I cannot retrieve any documents. Microservice (B) cannot communicate with Microservice (A).

Microservice (B) Service code :

```
@Service
public class TwitterElasticQueryWebClient implements ElasticQueryWebClient {

  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TwitterElasticQueryWebClient.class);

  private final WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder;
  private final ElasticQueryWebClientConfigData elasticQueryWebClientConfigData;

  public TwitterElasticQueryWebClient(
      @Qualifier("webClientBuilder") WebClient.Builder clientBuilder,
      ElasticQueryWebClientConfigData configData
  ) {
    this.webClientBuilder = clientBuilder;
    this.elasticQueryWebClientConfigData = configData;
  }

  @Override
  public Flux<ElasticQueryWebClientResponseModel> getAllData() {
    LOG.info("Querying all data");
    return webClientBuilder
        .build()
        .get()
        .uri("/")
        .accept(MediaType.valueOf(elasticQueryWebClientConfigData.getQuery().getAccept()))
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToFlux(ElasticQueryWebClientResponseModel.class);
  }

}
```

Microservice (B) config code :

```
@Configuration
public class WebClientConfig {

  private final ElasticQueryWebClientConfigData.WebClient webClientConfig;

  public WebClientConfig(ElasticQueryWebClientConfigData webClientConfigData) {
    this.webClientConfig = webClientConfigData.getWebClient();
  }

  @Bean("webClientBuilder")
  WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder() {
    return WebClient.builder()
        .baseUrl(webClientConfig.getBaseUrl())
        .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, webClientConfig.getContentType())
        .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, webClientConfig.getAcceptType())
        .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(HttpClient.from(getTcpClient())))
        .codecs(configurer -> configurer.defaultCodecs()
            .maxInMemorySize(webClientConfig.getMaxInMemorySize()));
  }

  private TcpClient getTcpClient() {
    return TcpClient.create()
        .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, webClientConfig.getConnectTimeoutMs())
        .doOnConnected(connection -> {
          connection.addHandlerLast(new ReadTimeoutHandler(webClientConfig.getReadTimeoutMs(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
          connection.addHandlerLast(new WriteTimeoutHandler(webClientConfig.getWriteTimeoutMs(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
        });
  }

}
```

Microservice (B) application.yml :

```
elastic-query-web-client:
  webclient:
    connect-timeout-ms: 10000
    read-timeout-ms: 10000
    write-timeout-ms: 10000
    max-in-memory-size: 10485760 # 10MB
    content-type: 'application/json'
    accept-type: 'text/event-stream'
    base-url: 'http://localhost:8183/reactive-elastic-query-service/documents'
  query:
    method: POST
    uri: "/get-doc-by-text"
    accept: ${elastic-query-web-client.webclient.accept-type}

server:
  port: 8184

spring:
  webflux:
    base-path: /reactive-elastic-query-web-client
  thymeleaf:
    cache: false
    reactive:
      max-chunk-size: 8192
  codec:
    max-in-memory-size: 25MB
```

Microservice (B) controller :

```
@Controller
public class QueryController {

  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(QueryController.class);

  private final ElasticQueryWebClient elasticQueryWebClient;

  public QueryController(ElasticQueryWebClient webClient) {
    this.elasticQueryWebClient = webClient;
  }

  @GetMapping("/all")
  public String queryAll(Model model) {
    Flux<ElasticQueryWebClientResponseModel> responseModels = elasticQueryWebClient.getAllData();
    responseModels = responseModels.log();
    IReactiveDataDriverContextVariable reactiveData = new ReactiveDataDriverContextVariable(responseModels, 1);
    model.addAttribute("elasticQueryWebClientResponseModels", reactiveData);
    model.addAttribute("searchText", "");
    model.addAttribute("elasticQueryWebClientRequestModel", ElasticQueryWebClientRequestModel.builder().build());
    LOG.info("Returning from reactive client controller for all data");
    return "home";
  }

}
```

There are no exceptions in the output consoles.
I don't see what I am missing here.

Comment: what is calling getAllData in microservice B?

Comment: It is called from a controller class :

Comment: try adding the Flux directly to the root of the model in the controller

Comment: Can you put some code please ?

Comment: in Microservice B, it looks like no one is subscribing to `responseModels`, as you are returning a `String` from the `queryAll` controller method. Change the response type from `String` to `Flux<ElasticQueryWebClientResponseModel>` and return `responseModels` from that method.